# Custom Function: apply in Stream

Tags: java, function, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have following code:

```
Function<String,Boolean> funcParse = (String f)-> {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(f);
    try
    {
        YearMonth.parse( date , formatter );
    }
    catch (DateTimeParseException e)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
};

Arrays.stream(MONTHYEAR_FORMATS.split("\\|")).findFirst(format -> funcParse.apply(format));
```

I have syntax warning here: `apply (java.lang.String) in Function cannot be applied to (<lambda parameter>)` What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `findFirst()` don't take any parameter. You might use `.filter(..).findFirst()`, and let `funcParse` be a `Predicate<String>`.

Comment: But where’s the sense in creating a `Function<String,Boolean>` instead of creating a `Predicate<String>` in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's actually a good candidate for `Bindable` (I *think* I've seen this as some of the Holger's answer, but can't find it right now).
So you have your usual parse method:

```
static boolean parse(String date, String format) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format);
    try {
        YearMonth.parse(date, formatter);
    } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

And you create a `bindValue` method:

```
public static <T, U> Predicate<U> bindValue(BiFunction<T, U, Boolean> f, T t) {
    return u -> f.apply(t, u);
}
```

Basically binding `date` to the `Predicate` - because `date` does not change, only the `format` does.

And then

```
 BiFunction<String, String, Boolean> toPredicate = Bindable::parse;
 Predicate<String> predicate = bindValue(toPredicate, date);
```

Usage for this is very easy:

```
 String date = "SomeDate";
 Predicate<String> predicate = bindValue(toPredicate, date);
 Arrays.stream(MONTHYEAR_FORMATS.split("|"))
       .filter(predicate)
       .findFirst();
```